# Sgen throws an error with internal setter in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, sgen, internalsvisibleto

Does SGen generate xml serialization assemblies only if all setters are public?

I've got this class in DummyProject:

```
 public class DummyClass
 {
   public int Sequence { get; internal set; }
 }
```

In my AssemblyInfo.cs, I've declared this:

```
 [assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("DummyProject.XmlSerializers")]
```

In my csproj, I've put this:

```
   <Target Name="AfterBuild"   DependsOnTargets="AssignTargetPaths;Compile;ResolveKeySource" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(IntermediateAssembly)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)">
<SGen BuildAssemblyName="$(TargetFileName)" BuildAssemblyPath="$(OutputPath)" References="@(ReferencePath)" ShouldGenerateSerializer="true" UseProxyTypes="false" KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)" KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)" DelaySign="$(DelaySign)" ToolPath="$(SGenToolPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="SerializationAssembly" ItemName="SerializationAssembly" />
</SGen>
```

Current error is:

Cannot deserialize type 'DummyProject.DummyClass' because it contains property 'Sequence' which has no public setter.

What I have tried:
1.  Now, if I take out the internal setter, I have no problems generating the DummyProject.XmlSerializer.

Am I missing something?

My assemblyinfo.cs does not contain this as listed in 1 of the pitfalls:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("")]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("")]
```

2. I also have tried signing my assemblies and modifying the InternalsVisibleTo to include the public key but I still get the same error.

Is it a problem with the InternalsVisibleTo?

Base on this post, SGen should still be able to generate the xml serialization assembly even with the internal setter.

[SGEN, InternalsVisibleTo and assembly signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055382/sgen-internalsvisibleto-and-assembly-signing)

3. I didn't use the post build steps to generate the xml serialization assembly.  I did it in Developer Command Prompt and the assembly is created successfully for classes with no internal setters. Now, I copied this assembly to my project output & change my property setter to internal.  I've got an error during serialization because of the internal setter.
   Of course, I've added the InternalsVisibleTo in my AssemblyInfo.cs..

Comment: Tried this in VS2008 and it works. SGen in VS2008 works fine even if internal setters existed.  Bug in VS2012?

Comment: For reference: *Visual Studio 2013*'s `sgen` is also generating errors for classes marked as `internal`

Answer (score 0):

I think Joe may have found the solution:

> "In the InternalsVisibleTo attribute, you need to specify the full
>   public key, not just the public key token.
>
> See this answer to a similar question and this MSDN article for info
>   on how to get the public key."

**REFERENCE**

[SGEN, InternalsVisibleTo and assembly signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055382/sgen-internalsvisibleto-and-assembly-signing?rq=1)