# Unit Testing with Moq in Visual studio 2012

Tags: oop, unit-testing, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, moq

I am using moq library (Moq) in Visual studio 2012 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting) and would like to know How to write unit test class for the below Employee class using Moq.

```
   publc class Employee

    {

      private Deparment _objectA; //Class
      protected IManager  _objectB; //Interface

      public Employee(Deparment objectA, IManager  objectB)
       {

         _objectA=objectA;
         _objectB=objectB;

       }

       internal void EmpMethod1()
       {

       }

       internal void EmpMethod2()
       {

        }

       internal void EmpMethod3()
       {

       }

       }
   }

    public interface IManager

     {
          Manager GetManager(int id);

          Void AddManager(MgrName);
      }
```

Comment: What are your public methods that you want to test?

Comment: I have internal methods in the Employee class and I guess we can test internal methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate from:

[How to Mock the Internal Method of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772621/how-to-mock-the-internal-method-of-a-class)

Also there is a workaround described in the following article by using attributes with you projects:

[Mocking Internal Types with Moq](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqInternals.aspx)

You can also consider using a non-proxy mocking library like TypeMock, JustMock or Microsoft Fakes.