# Moq calls original internal method in spite of Setup

Tags: c#, moq

Hello,

I'm having trouble getting my class to call a Moq'd method. My situation is thus:

```
public class ResetPasswordsTask : IRefreshTimeTask
{
    public long ExecutionId => 2100;
    public bool Enabled => true;
    public Dictionary<string, object> Params { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, Type>[] RequiredParams => new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, Type>("targetConfigs", typeof(InMemoryConfiguration))
    };
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    internal IConfiguration SandboxConfig;
    internal IPartnerService PartnerService;
    internal ISalesForceBulkDataInserter DataInserter;

    public void Execute()
    {
        SandboxConfig = (IConfiguration)Params["targetConfigs"];
        PartnerService = Login.SalesforceApiLogin(true, SandboxConfig);
        DataInserter = new SalesForceBulkDataInserter();
        //InitialiseImapClient();

        // Retrieve users
        var users = TestAutomation.Salesforce.Pages.Base.User.GetUsers(PartnerService, SandboxConfig.Refresh_Usernames);

        // Upsert emails
        var emailUpsertResults = UpsertEmails(users, SandboxConfig.IMAP_Email);

        // Hit mailbox and visit confirmation links
        var activatedUsers = emailUpsertResults.Values.Where(r => r.Status == EmailResetStatusEnum.Success).Select(r => r.User).ToList();
        var confirmationLinkResults = ConfirmEmailChanges(activatedUsers);

        // Upsert passwords
        // All the users, except those for whom email update failed
        var passwordUpdateUsers = users.Except(confirmationLinkResults.Values.Where(r => !r.Success).Select(r => r.User)).ToList();
        var passwordUpsertResults = UpsertPasswords(passwordUpdateUsers);

        // Hit mailbox for new tokens
        var completeResetResults = RetrieveTokens(passwordUpsertResults.Values.Where(r => r.Success));

        var output = string.Join("\n", completeResetResults.Values.Where(c => c.Success).Select(result => string.Join("\t", new List<string> { result.User.Username, result.Password, result.SecurityToken })));
        //Logger.Info(output);
        Logger.Info(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("."));
        Logger.Info(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        OpenSslEncryption.EncryptToFile(SandboxConfig.EncryptionPassword, "passwords.enc", output);
    }

    // Results are keyed by username
    internal IDictionary<string, EmailResetResult> UpsertEmails(ICollection<User> users, string newEmail)
    {
        var results = users.ToDictionary(u => u.Username, u => new EmailResetResult(u));

        Logger.Info($"Updating emails for {users.Count} users");
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Logger.Info($"updating email for {user.Username} users");
            var result = results[user.Username];

            // Prevent upserting the profile
            if (user.ProfileId != null)
            {
                Logger.Info("Preventing profile upsert");
                user.ProfileId.SalesForceId = user.ProfileId.OriginId;
            }

            // If the user has had their email set to what we're setting now, they can be skipped
            if (user.Email.Equals(newEmail, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && user.IsActive)
            {
                Logger.Info($"User {user.Username} has their email set to {newEmail}; skipping");
                result.Status = EmailResetStatusEnum.Skipped;
                continue;
            }

            // Otherwise, set the email and carry on
            user.Email = newEmail;
            user.IsActive = true;

            // dataInserter.Upsert won't produce errors individually, and instead only log faulty upserts
            try
            {
                DataInserter.Upsert(new List<User> { user });
                Logger.Info($"Activated user {user.Username}");
                result.Status = EmailResetStatusEnum.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var error = $"Failed to update the email for user {user.Username} to {newEmail}. Error details: {e}";
                Logger.Error(TestAutomation.Framework.Core.Logger.Logger.FormatJson(error));
                result.ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
                result.Status = EmailResetStatusEnum.Failure;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    internal IDictionary<string, Result> ConfirmEmailChanges(ICollection<User> users)
    {
        var results = users.ToDictionary(u => u.Username, u => new Result(u));

        // Ran as a task to have a timeout
        Task.Run(() => ConfirmEmailChangesTask(results, users)).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(users.Count * 5));

        return results;
    }

    internal void ConfirmEmailChangesTask(IDictionary<string, Result> results, ICollection<User> users)
    {
        var remainingUsers = new HashSet<User>(users);
        while (true)
        {
            // Wait a bit; either for the emails to come in, or to give the webserver breathing room
            Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));

            Logger.Info($"Opening mailbox for {SandboxConfig.IMAP_Email}");
            using (var imapClient = CreateImapClient())
            {
                var messages = imapClient.SearchMessages(SearchQuery.NotSeen.And(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))));
                Logger.Info($"Found {messages.Count} messages");

                var remainingUsersCopy = new HashSet<User>(remainingUsers);
                Logger.Info($"Attempting to confirm emails for {remainingUsers.Count} users");
                foreach (var user in remainingUsersCopy)
                {
                    Logger.Info("Attempting to confirm email change for " + user.Username);
                    foreach (var message in messages.Where(m => m.MimeMessage.TextBody.Contains(user.Username) && m.MimeMessage.Subject.Contains("Sandbox: Finish changing your Salesforce")))
                    {
                        Logger.Info("Message found");
                        var confirmLink = GetEmailConfirmationLink(message);
                        if (confirmLink == null) continue;

                        // Visit the URL
                        var request = WebRequest.Create(confirmLink);
                        request.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).TotalMilliseconds;
                        var result = results[user.Username];
                        try
                        {
                            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                            {
                                var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                                if (statusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                {
                                    var error = $"Failed to load the email change confirmation link: {confirmLink}. HTTP Response: ({statusCode})";
                                    Logger.Error(TestAutomation.Framework.Core.Logger.Logger.FormatJson(error));
                                    result.Success = false;
                                    result.ErrorMessage = error;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (WebException e)
                        {
                            Logger.Error($"Request failed: {e.Message}\nWill retry later");
                            continue;
                        }

                        result.Success = true;
                        remainingUsers.Remove(user);
                        imapClient.MarkAsRead(message);

                        //Break down mailbox checks
                        Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!remainingUsers.Any())
                break;
        }
    }

    #region MailboxInteraction

    internal static string GetEmailConfirmationLink(Message message)
    {
        // Extract confirmation URL
        var confirmLinkMatch = Regex.Match(message.MimeMessage.TextBody, @"([a-z]+:\/\/.*\.salesforce\.com\/\S*)");
        return !confirmLinkMatch.Success ? null : confirmLinkMatch.Groups[1].Value;
    }

    internal static string GetSecurityToken(Message message)
    {
        var tokenMatch = Regex.Match(message.MimeMessage.TextBody, @"Security token \(case-sensitive\): (?<token>\w+)");
        return !tokenMatch.Success ? null : tokenMatch.Groups[1].Value;
    }

    internal virtual IMailClient CreateImapClient()
    {
        return new IMAPClient(SandboxConfig.IMAP_Username, SandboxConfig.IMAP_Password, SandboxConfig.IMAP_URL);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WhenResettingUserPasswords
{
    private const string ConfirmationLink = "test://testdomain.salesforce.com/test/";

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void WebRequestSetup()
    {
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("test", TestableWebRequestCreateFactory.GetFactory());
        var uri = new Uri("test://testdomain.salesforce.com/test/");
        var expectedRequest = new TestableWebRequest(uri);
        expectedRequest.EnqueueResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success", "Even more success!", false);
        TestableWebRequestCreateFactory.GetFactory().AddRequest(expectedRequest);
    }

    private static SetupBag Setup()
    {
        var bag = new SetupBag
        {
            Logger = new InMemoryLogger(),
            EmailConfirmationLink = ConfirmationLink,
            SecurityToken = "TheSecurityToken",
            Environment = "EnvName",
            EnvironmentUrl = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc/",
            User = new User
            {
                IsActive = false,
                Username = "joe.bloggs@company.com",
                Email = "joe.bloggs=company.com@example.com",
                OriginId = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"
            }
        };


        var task = new Mock<Tasks.ResetPasswordsTask>(MockBehavior.Strict) { CallBase = true };
        task.Object.Logger = bag.Logger;

        var confirmMessage = new Message
        {
            UID = new UniqueId(0),
            MimeMessage = new MimeMessage
            {
                Subject = "Sandbox: Finish changing your Salesforce",
                Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = "Confirm email change for joe.bloggs@company.com: " + bag.EmailConfirmationLink }
            }
        };
        var tokenMessage = new Message
        {
            UID = new UniqueId(1),
            MimeMessage = new MimeMessage
            {
                Subject = "Sandbox: Your new Salesforce security token",
                Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = "New security token for joe.bloggs@company.com: " + bag.SecurityToken }
            }
        };

        var mailClientMock = new Mock<IMailClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mailClientMock.Setup(m => m.SearchMessages(It.IsAny<SearchQuery>())).Returns(new List<Message> { confirmMessage, tokenMessage });
        task.Setup(t => t.CreateImapClient()).Returns(() => mailClientMock.Object);

        var dataInserterMock = new Mock<ISalesForceBulkDataInserter>();
        dataInserterMock.Setup(m => m.Upsert(It.IsAny<List<User>>(), false));

        var config = new InMemoryConfiguration
        {
            IMAP_Email = "test.email@company.com"
        };
        task.Object.SandboxConfig = config;

        bag.Task = task;

        return bag;
    }

    [Test]
    public void UpsertEmailsTest()
    {
        var bag = Setup();
        var task = bag.Task;

        var output = task.Object.ConfirmEmailChanges(new[] { bag.User });

        Assert.IsTrue(output.ContainsKey(bag.User.Username));
        Assert.IsTrue(output[bag.User.Username].Success);
        Assert.IsEmpty(output[bag.User.Username].ErrorMessage);
        Assert.AreEqual(task.Object.SandboxConfig.IMAP_Email, output[bag.User.Username].User.Username);
    }
}
```

Now, the result is that calling `task.Object.ConfirmEmailChanges()` raises an exception about arguments to `new IMAPClient()` being null, which should not have been called at all. I could not find anything obviously wrong, but that might just be because I'm not familiar enough with Moq or the way my codebase does testing.

Yes, I know I'm mocking a class I want to test. I know it's a bad idea, and I'm aiming for a redesign. I cannot inject `IMailClient` as a dependency because it needs to be instantiated anew frequently. I have also seen this sort of technique used in our codebase, and it seemed to work.

Comment: Did you try to remove the strict mock behaviour?

Comment: Yes. Originally it wasn't set to strict.

Comment: Since you use {CallBase= true} the virtual methods will get called if your setup doesent manage to target the correct calls. If you remove both this and the strict do you get the same error message?

Comment: I considered that, but I can't do this - `UpsertEmailsTest` needs to call unmocked `ConfirmEmailChanges` for the test to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are mocking a concrete class and not an interface then you must make the method you want to mock `virtual`.

Edit: in your new code the method is also marked as `internal`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772621/how-to-mock-the-internal-method-of-a-class).

Comment: I forgot to include `virtual` - I did make the method virtual, or Moq will complain.

Comment: That seems to be it. I've been actively avoiding making the class too transparent, I see that I have little choice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your method as `virtual` or Moq is unable to override it. C# is not like Java - only members that are specifically marked are able to be overridden.

### EDIT

The code you've posted should work - here is a Linqpad MVCE I generated based on your code, demonstrating that it works correctly. Therefore, you will need to post your *actual* code, as it has a bug in it.

```
void Main()
{
    // Arrange
    var foo = new Mock<Foo> { CallBase = true };
    var bar = new Mock<IBar>();
    bar.Setup(b => b.Value).Returns(2);
    // setup an IBar mock
    foo.Setup(f => f.CreateBar()).Returns(bar.Object);

    // Act
    var results = foo.Object.DoStuff();

    results.Dump(); // Prints "2"
}

public class Foo
{
    public int DoStuff()
    {
        var bar = CreateBar();
        return bar.Value;
    }

    public virtual IBar CreateBar()
    {
        return new RealBar();
    }
}

public interface IBar 
{
    int Value { get;}
}

public class RealBar : IBar
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, I forgot to include the keyword. Moq raises a pretty clear complaint if you don't!

Comment: Please can you post your actual code, or an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you've posted should work, so the devil will be in the detail of your actual code.