# i am writing a unit test using NUnit with Moq. when an internal method is called which have httpcontext its returning null values. here is my code

Tags: c#, nunit

```
internal string GetFullUserName()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
            {
                return ((ICorePrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).CoreUser.FirstName + " " + ((ICorePrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).CoreUser.LastName;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

when this method is called its always returning null values. how to mock it? i tried using httpcontext mocking but i am not sure why its not working

Comment: Do you mean you want to mock the method `GetFullUserName`? Moq requires it to be `virtual`. `internal` is ok if you follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772621/how-to-mock-the-internal-method-of-a-class

Comment: You should edit your question to add the test method itself, showing how you have tried to use Moq.