# Accessing internal class through Reflection is failing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to get internal class(in external assembly) through reflection. This one is failing for me,

```
Type.GetType("MyFullyQualifiedInternalClass")
```

Comment: Try getting the assembly and enumerating through its types. You may need to add an "InternalsVisobleTo" attribute to make it work; if it is a 3-rd party assembly, security model may prevent you from accessing its internals altogether.

Comment: got answer from this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513612/instantiating-an-internal-class-and-casting-it-as-a-given-type