# InternalsVisibleTo PublicKey is ignored

Tags: c#

I have two strong named assemblies A.dll and B.dll. A.dll has internal classes. B.dll uses internal classes from A.dll. 
I use

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("B,PublicKey=[public key of B.dll]")]
```

in A.dll. 
It works fine, I can use internal classes from A.dll in B.dll. When I change assembly name in InternalsVisibleTo it stops working, as expected, but if I change only a public key (set wrong public key) it continue working, so it ignored PublicKey parameter.

I use Assembly.Load, for loading assembly.

What is the problem or InternalsVisibleTo not sensitive to PublicKey?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504257/internalsvisibleto-attribute-isnt-working

Comment: What do you mean by stops working? Does it compile? Does it start?

Comment: I have inverse problem, all works, but it shouldn't. Or I don't understand use of PublicKey parameter here. @ctescu

Comment: Assembly loads dynamically, so it has runtime error. But it works as exepcted, here is no problem. @Erno de Weerd

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106880/internalsvisibleto-attribute-isnt-working

Comment: @Ian Ringrose I have another problem

Comment: Are you sure the assemblies are signed?

Comment: Loading should be fine, it should stop you from accessing the internal types

Comment: Yes,they are signed and i can get their PublicKey by sn.exe. Problem is that I can access internal types even if PublicKey doesn't match, I thought it should be secured from such attempts. @Erno de Weerd