# InternalsVisibleTo not working for MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have looked into [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=pcNu0W9MDCWarow6HXOoOA&cp=18&gs_id=6&xhr=t&q=Internalsvisibleto&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Internalsvisibleto&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=356e729b7a15c7f0&biw=1454&bih=726&ion=1) and [stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106880/internalsvisibleto-attribute-isnt-working) and read all the posts regarding how to get InternalsVisibleTo to work.

But its not working for me.

Please do not down vote this question because I have tried my best to look and implement the answers on the forums..

My code is as follows:

*** Inside TestInternal project ***

```
namespace TestInteral
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyProviderTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestBar()
        {
            bool retval = false;

            retval = new MyProviderClass().Bar();

            Assert.AreEqual(true,retval);
        }

    }
}
```

*** Inside Provider Project ***

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestInternal")]
namespace Provider
{

    public class MyProviderClass
    {
        internal bool Bar()
        {
            return true;

        }

        private void UseBar()
        {
            bool retval = Bar();

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in my test class.

**Error 1   'Provider.MyProviderClass' does not contain a definition for 'Bar' and no extension method 'Bar' accepting a first argument of type 'Provider.MyProviderClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Please let me know how I could use the InternalsVisibleTo correctly so I could correctly test the *Internal* method in the MyProviderClass.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you have Provider project referenced in TestInternal? Did you try building Provider project first? Is Provider project signed?

Comment: Provider is referenced in TestInternal. I successfully *first* built Provider Project. Provider Project is NOT signed. thanks..

Comment: According to MS documentation both assemblies should be either unsigned or signed

Comment: Can you confirm that `TestInteral` is the name of the _assembly_, and not just the namespace?

Comment: Right, plus there's some stuff to do with the keys... "TestInternal" in your InternalsVisibleTo attribute is name of the project? It should be... It's just coincidence that it matches name of the namespace then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have just copied and pasted your EXACT code into the question, this is a simple typo.  I noticed your namespace on the test assembly is `TestInteral` with no 'N'. And your `InternalsVisibleTo` declaration has the last 'N':

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestInternal")]
```

That's probably all it is.

Comment: this code is working now.. thanks for all those responded.. this could be used as a tutorial who is trying it for the first time.