# InternalsVisibleTo does not work

Tags: c#, internalsvisibleto

I insert the line:

`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")]`

inside my project under test( `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`) where `MyTests` is the name of the Unit Test project. But for some reason I still cannot access the internal methods from the unit test project.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It's been a looong time but I think the two assemblies have to be signed with the same signature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [InternalsVisibleTo attribute isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106880/internalsvisibleto-attribute-isnt-working)

Comment: I read that on a question in SO but I am not sure if that may create problems in the future. I also couldnt manage to sign my assemblies.

Comment: @Cemre: You don't need to sign, if both assemblies are unsigned it should all work. But do read the answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If your assembly is signed with a strong name [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106880/internalsvisibleto-attribute-isnt-working/107958#107958).

Otherwise check that the name of your test assembly really is "MyTests.dll" (it doesn't have to match the project name, though it will by default).

Comment: +1 yep, I remember wasting some time on this issue : the assembly _file system name_ of the test app was different than its project name :)

Comment: +1 as well. The default class or unit test name is valid, but never what I will have renamed it by the time it gets published. The resulting .dll will retain the first saved file name until the 'Assembly name' is changed in the project's properties.

Comment: When your projects are unsigned also make sure that the application project (the one containing the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")]` friend reference) does not contain `[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("")]` in its AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Answer (score 16):

Let's break it down a bit as many of us have experienced this slight mix-up in the past...

Assembly A has your internal class.
Assembly B has your unit tests.

You wish to grant the internals of assembly A visibility in assembly B.

You need to put the InternalsVisibleTo assembly attribute inside assembly A and grant access to assembly B.

Answer (score 6):

You still need your test project to reference your main project.

This can be easy to overlook and if you have no existing test code this may appear like the InternalsVisibleTo is not functioning.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after renaming a namespace. Basically the in .cs files was the new namespace but in the `.csproj` and `AssemblyInfo.cs` it was the old namespace.

```
namespace newNamespace {
   ....
}
```

So, I changed in `.csproj` the following to the new namespace:

```
    <RootNamespace>oldnamespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>oldnamespace</AssemblyName>
```

And in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("oldnamespace")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("oldnamespace")]
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was coding to an Interface. As interfaces can only specify public properties the internal properties were not present on the interface.

Make sure you're not doing the same thing as I was!

I changed:

```
Assert.IsNotNull((exportFileManager)?.ThumbnailFileExporter);
```

To:

```
Assert.IsNotNull((exportFileManager as ExportFileManager)?.ThumbnailFileExporter);
```

Comment: Took me forever to find this answer. Cannot understand why the internal explicitly declared implementation of the interface was not recognized,

Comment: Explicitly implemented methods are never visible (that's the point); you have to cast the object to the interface in order to get access to those method implementations.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 don't you mean cast the interface to the concrete class? Sure, I understand why it happens but my point it that it's an easy mistake to make perhaps without realising.

Answer (score 2):

I made the incorrect assumption that `InternalsVisibleTo` will help in accessing `Private` methods too.

Here are some other aspects that can lead to this error:

- Your class is either `internal` or `public`
- Your method is `internal`
- The `InternalsVisibleTo` property contains the full namespace of your test project.

Comment: My class was public. I can't tell you how long this had me banging my head against the desk.

Comment: So the class must be internal not just some of the methods?

Comment: That would surprise me. My class can't be internal or public?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose internals from strong named assembly to another strong named friend assembly only. But non-strong named assembly can expose internals to strong named friend assembly.